# Proving continuity of functions on open intervals

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

let's say we have a function $f(x)$ defined as follows:

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
 x \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{if} \ -1 < x < 1 \\
 x - 1 \ \ \ \ \  \text{if} \ x \leq -1 \\
 x + 1 \ \ \ \ \  \text{if} \ x \geq 1
\end{cases}
$$

My question is: is $f(x)$ continuous on the open interval $(-1,1)$?

It seems that it must be the case that $f(x)$ is continuous on that interval because regardless of how close I let $x$ get to $-1$ on that interval, the value of $f(x)$ approaches $-1$, but I'm not sure how to formally show this because:

$\lim_{x \to -1^{-}} f(x) = -2$ and $lim_{x\to-1^{+}}f(x) = -1$.

Could someone show me how to prove this, and ideally similar cases for continuity?

Comment: The limits that you have computed are when $x$ approaches $-1$. But $-1$ does not belong to $(-1, 1)$. So having the lower limit not equal to the upper limit is something you should not worry about if you are asking about continuity on $(-1, 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In this interval $f(x)=x$ is cont'. The left limit of -1 and the right limit of 1 does not matter, it's outside of the interval.

Answer (score 0):

On the open intervall $(-1,1)$ we have $f(x)=x.$ Hence $f$ is continuous on that intervall.

Answer (score 0):

On $(-1,1)$ the function is just $f(x)=x$. The values of $f$ outside this interval have no relevance to continuity on this interval.

Comment: My understanding is that a function is continuous on an interval $I$ iff it is continuous at every point on $I$. An interval is continuous at $x = a$ if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = f(a)$. But limits won't work for the edges of an interval. So for more complex functions (here it is obvious $f(x) = x$ is defined on the interval), how can I prove that the interval is continuous, because clearly I can't use limits.

Comment: It would be good if you give an example of the kind you are thinking about because I don't know where exactly your confusion is. @DataDao